# Fill UL Space with 2nd to last Li?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have been trying to get this to work for about 2 days now, but i can get nothing. Here is my layout. I have a navbar with some elements, and the last one is floating right. This leaves a lot of space left between the last and the second to last li. How can i make that second to last li fill up the ul? I already tried to treat it as a table, but that did not work. Here is some of my css:

```
.NavBar > ul {
list-style:inside none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display: table;
width:100%;
}

.NavBar > ul > li {
list-style:inside none;
display:block;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.NavBar > ul > li > a:hover {
background:#111;
}

.NavBar > ul > li:nth-last-child(2) {
list-style:inside none;
display:table-cell;
}
```

If there is any more code you need, just tell me and i will post it. Thanks.

Here is what i need to happen. [image]

The News li need to grow to fill up space in between it and the login li.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are floating the last li right instead of left?  If you keep the floats left you shouldn't have the spacing problem.

If this doesn't help, I think you're going to need to give more details as to what you want to accomplish.

---

Okay, I suspect there's more that you haven't yet told us, but take a look at this quick and dirty sample and let me know how close it comes to your goal:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.NavBar > ul {
list-style:inside none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}

.NavBar > ul > li {
list-style:inside none;
display:block;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 10%;
background-color: #FFDDDD;
}

.NavBar > ul > li > a:hover {
background:#111;
}

.NavBar > ul > li:last-child {
float: right;
background-color: #DDFFDD;
}

.NavBar > ul > li:nth-last-child(2) {
width: 60%;
background-color: #DDDDFF;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class='NavBar'>
    <ul>
      <li>Widgets</>
      <li>Boojuns</>
      <li>Snarf</>
      <li>Xyzzy</>
      <li>Plugh</>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

The background colors are just to help us see what's happening.

Comment: I am trying to get the 2nd to last li to fill the space between it and the last one. The last is on the very right of the menu.

Comment: Well, lacking further information, the answer is "make it wider".

Comment: We'll be glad to try to help if we can understand you goal.  I'd suggest you post either a picture of what's going wrong or all of the html and css for your nav bar.

Comment: Thanks. let me do that now